# Ansible loop within a loop

Tags: loops, ansible, nested-loops

I'm really struggling to get my head around loops within Ansible when it comes to wanting more than one loop in a task.
Right now I'm writing a task to create some registry entries within Ansible and have the following which does work,

```
- name: Windows SSL/TLS Configuration
  ansible.windows.win_regedit:
    path: HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\{{ item.type }}
    name: '{{ item.property }}'
    data: '{{ item.value }}'
    type: dword
    state: present
  loop:
  - type: Server
    property: Enabled
    value: 0
  - type: Server
    property: DisabledByDefault
    value: 1
  - type: Client
    property: Enabled
    value: 0
  - type: Client
    property: DisabledByDefault
    value: 1
```

However what I want to do is replace "SSL 3.0" with something like "{{ item.protocol }}" and be able to have it replaced with "SSL 2.0", "SSL 3.0" and "TLS 1.0", then creating the same entries within each of those.
I'd have liked to do them all within the same task, rather than having to run the exact same task 3 times with just one difference in the path.

Is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible - Enumerate list when looping on list product (nested loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596379/ansible-enumerate-list-when-looping-on-list-product-nested-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loop_control` to set `loop_var`. Otherwise the inner and outer loop use the same loop variable, which does not work.

See the documentation: [Defining inner and outer variable names with loop_var](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#defining-inner-and-outer-variable-names-with-loop-var)

The documentation explains, that you have to put the inner loop into a different file in order to include it with `include_tasks`.

If you do not want that, you can add the protocols to each item in order to use [`with_subelements`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html). Example:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    protocols:
      - "SSL 2.0"
      - "SSL 3.0"
      - "TLS 1.0"
    keys:
      - type: Server
        property: Enabled
        value: 0
        protocols: "{{ protocols }}"
      - type: Server
        property: DisabledByDefault
        value: 1
        protocols: "{{ protocols }}"
      - type: Client
        property: Enabled
        value: 0
        protocols: "{{ protocols }}"
      - type: Client
        property: DisabledByDefault
        value: 1
        protocols: "{{ protocols }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{item.0.type}} {{item.0.property}} {{item.0.value}} {{item.1}}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ keys }}"
        - protocols
```

This will generate 12 keys:

```
$ ansible-playbook example.yaml
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does
not match 'all'


PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'type': 'Server', 'property': 'Enabled', 'value': 0}, 'SSL 2.0']) => {
    "msg": "Server Enabled 0 SSL 2.0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'type': 'Server', 'property': 'Enabled', 'value': 0}, 'SSL 3.0']) => {
    "msg": "Server Enabled 0 SSL 3.0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'type': 'Server', 'property': 'Enabled', 'value': 0}, 'TLS 1.0']) => {
    "msg": "Server Enabled 0 TLS 1.0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'type': 'Server', 'property': 'DisabledByDefault', 'value': 1}, 'SSL 2.0']) => {
    "msg": "Server DisabledByDefault 1 SSL 2.0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'type': 'Server', 'property': 'DisabledByDefault', 'value': 1}, 'SSL 3.0']) => {
    "msg": "Server DisabledByDefault 1 SSL 3.0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'type': 'Server', 'property': 'DisabledByDefault', 'value': 1}, 'TLS 1.0']) => {
    "msg": "Server DisabledByDefault 1 TLS 1.0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'type': 'Client', 'property': 'Enabled', 'value': 0}, 'SSL 2.0']) => {
    "msg": "Client Enabled 0 SSL 2.0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'type': 'Client', 'property': 'Enabled', 'value': 0}, 'SSL 3.0']) => {
    "msg": "Client Enabled 0 SSL 3.0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'type': 'Client', 'property': 'Enabled', 'value': 0}, 'TLS 1.0']) => {
    "msg": "Client Enabled 0 TLS 1.0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'type': 'Client', 'property': 'DisabledByDefault', 'value': 1}, 'SSL 2.0']) => {
    "msg": "Client DisabledByDefault 1 SSL 2.0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'type': 'Client', 'property': 'DisabledByDefault', 'value': 1}, 'SSL 3.0']) => {
    "msg": "Client DisabledByDefault 1 SSL 3.0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'type': 'Client', 'property': 'DisabledByDefault', 'value': 1}, 'TLS 1.0']) => {
    "msg": "Client DisabledByDefault 1 TLS 1.0"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: So is it possible to define the outer_item loop within the same task? Or does it need to be defined as a task in and of itself as demonstrated in the linked documentation?

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the push in the right direction I needed!
I've now got everything, including the vars, rolled into a single task that's doing exactly what I needed it to.